# Increased time animate in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

same as title, example:

```
$(#someDiv).animate({left:'70px'}, 500);
```

but now I want time animation increased from 0 to 500:

```
$(#someDiv).animate({left:'70px'}, time);
```

What is the solution? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need some correction in loops but I think this logic will work for you.

```
var start_time;
var end_time = 500;
for ( start_time = 0; start_time < end_time; start_time++ ) {
   $(#someDiv).animate({left:'70px'}, start_time);
   if (start_time > 500 ){ 
     break;
     // Put alert for testing purpose like alert ('StartTime:'+start_time);
   }

}
```